# Italic text is smaller than regular text when using clearpage and the scrlayer-scrpage package

Tags: fontsize, italic

I am using Luatex and KOMA-script. I have the issue that the italic font is consistently set to size 10pt it seems, and I don't understand it. In my M(not)WE below, the issue is present, but it isn't when removing the line that loads the scrlayer-scrpage package or removing the \clearpage. I'm not using the package in this example to keep it simple, but in my main document I want to use it. What is going on here? Also, this issue doesn't happen for most other fonts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% load packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

%%%%% Head and Footnotes %%%%%
\usepackage[]{scrlayer-scrpage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% begin of document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
Some Text
\clearpage  % or cleardoublepage or newpage, all produce the problem
This is a text in normalsize. \emph{This appears smaller than it should. }\textit{This appears too small as well.}\\
Look at the size of Letters: u\emph{u}\textit{u}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is being set to `\small` for the header/footer (and then somehow "leaking" into the document body text). Reset it with  `\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\normalcolor\itshape}` - but that is not a fix.

Comment: You don't need `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}` because this is the default. And if you remove it, again `LMRoman12-Italic` is used instead of `LMRoman10-Italic`.

Comment: @cabohah thanks, you're right. Do you know, how I would set `LMRoman12-Italic` explicitly?

Comment: `\setmainfont[ItalicFont=LMRoman12-Italic.otf]{Latin Modern Roman}`

Comment: BTW: Strange enough, `scrlayer-scrpage` doesn't even use the italic font, it just uses `\slshape`, which should be the slanted font. And indeed `\setmainfont[SlantedFont=LMRomanSlant12-Regular.otf]{Latin Modern Roman}` also helps to switch back to LMRoman12-Italic. So it seems to be a problem with the automatic font mapping of `fontspec`. But currently I do not know the trigger.

Comment: @Cicada AFAIK `scrlayer-scrpage` does not use `\small` by default.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with `report` and without `scrlayer-scrpage` just with `\slshape` or `\slshape\normalfont` in the document preamble and even somewhere after `\begin{document}`. So it seems to be a `fontspec` issue not related to KOMA-Script.

Comment: See https://github.com/latex3/fontspec/issues/486 for a very simple example.

Comment: @cabohah thanks for your effort. Your findings made me try using XeLaTeX for compiling, and interestingly it doesn't have the issue. So it might be a LuaLaTeX problem rather than 'fontspec'? It's really strange.

Comment: @J_mu `fontspec.sty` is only a wrapper to `fontspec-xetex.sty` or `luaotfload` and `fontspec-luatex.sty`. So I'm not sure, whether this is a `luaotfload` problem, a `fontspec` problem or a LuaTeX problem. I think, my report at the `fontspec` issue tracker is a good starting point to find it out and maybe address another one.

Answer (score 6):

Fonts with optical sizes are sometimes a bit complicated. Declare the slanted font explicitly:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% load packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[SlantedFont=LatinModernRoman/I]

%%%%% Head and Footnotes %%%%%
\usepackage[]{scrlayer-scrpage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% begin of document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
Some Text
\clearpage  % or cleardoublepage or newpage, all produce the problem
This is a text in normalsize. \emph{This appears smaller than it should. }\textit{This appears too small as well.}\\
Look at the size of Letters: u\emph{u}\textit{u}

\end{document}
```

[image]